# Database design to accomodate daisy chained records

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling

Question regarding database design/structure. Suppose you're modeling a database for an insurance company that sells policies/contracts. Say the companies policy is that all contracts are not extendable and any renewed policies/contracts require a new policy/contract number to be created and issued. For renewed or unmodified contracts, you could have two or more records that are identical. What is the best way to model this database to give it's consumers an easy way of tracing these 'daisy chained' records and separate them from new ones or ones that are legitimately different without the use of creative SQL queries? Would another key field be appropriate? Is there any other way?

Thx;

Comment: Version numbers

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new table that basically keeps track of the chain of policies.  Each time a policy is renewed, create an entry in this table so that the renewed, or current, policy points to the old policy.  This will make displaying policy histories easier whether you're displaying history for the current policy or an older policy.  Also, if you need to keep track of different categories of objects (policies, contracts, or what-have-you), you can add a object type column as a solution - that way you don't have a bunch of these types of tables cluttering your database!